# Merge/update associative arrays with overlapping keys

Tags: php

I have two associative arrays with string keys, like this:

```
$base_array = array(
'foo' => '42',
'bar' => '13');
```

and

```
$update_array = array(
'bar' => '14',
'blah' => '3.1415');
```

Question 1: I want to update my $base_array with data from $update_array in such a way that:

1. If a key is only in $base_array, but not in $update_array, its value be kept intact;
2. If a key is in both arrays, its value be updated from $update_array;
3. If a key is only in $update_array, both the key and its value be copied into $base_array.

Is there a short way to accomplish this? Any hint or piece of code is very welcome.

Question 2: Besides this, is there a quick way to visualize a joint list of keys from both arrays, without duplicates? Just keys, no values.

Comment: take a look at array_keys here http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Question 1:**

That is exactly what [`array_merge()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) does:

```
$new_array = array_merge($base_array,$update_array);
```

**Question 2:**

To get an array of the unique keys, you can merge the arrays and then use [`array_keys()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php):

```
$keys = array_keys(array_merge($base_array,$update_array));
```